# Stationary distribution from hitting/first return time

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a finite, irreducible Markov chain and know the hitting and first return times for all states. Is there a general expression using these for the stationary distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is! In fact, all you need is the first return times; the stationary distribution is $\pi(x) = \frac{1}{\mathbb E_x[T_x]}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, is the proof for that difficult?

Comment: Good question! Depends on the user, as always. You can find the theorem statement in Theorem 5.5.11 of Durrett's PTE (5th edition): https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will have a look!